# Sound Pool Permissions

Tags: android

I am playing audio through my app using the sound pool, do I need to ask for certain app permissions?

If I do, which ones do I need?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need any permissions for using the `SoundPool` or media player.

Just go through these tutorials. It will helpful for you.

[Play Audio resource using sound pool](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/play-audio-resources-using-soundpool.html)

[Play foreground and background music using SoundPool and MediaPlayer](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/play-foreground-and-background-music.html)